# Windows 10 - restore start menu size to default

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

so I accidentally resized my win10 start menu and don't know the default size... Can you tell me how to reset it or send me a screenshot of default windows 10 start menu on `1366x768` resolution? Would be very appreciated!

Comment: The default is 2 columns. One column has 4 big or 8 small icons. And you can only change size by column.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I didn't mention that horizontally I got the size right, but vertically - not quite. And no, you can resize start menu vertically too in addition to horizontally.

Comment: Ah, good point. I actually didn't know you can resize vertically. :D I'll have to check it at work tomorrow then.

Comment: Alright, I can change the start menu height to maximum but I'm not entirely sure if that's how it was... So frustrating

Comment: Have you considered searching for `Windows 10 Startmenu` and then check google's images? lots of images, and all seem to have the default size.

Comment: But when I compare their size in pixels it's different... Any progress yet?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think it matters how big your resolution is, and that the start menu is adjusted based on that after first launch. Mine is slightly larger than 50% of my screen vertically. about 55% of the screen.

Comment: Well my native resolution is 1366x768.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Personalization->Start->Turn on and off "Use start full screen" and your start menu size will be back to default.